# Cost Analysis for npm registry creation

Tags: github, npm, azure-devops, registry

I want to create a npm registry for my package and need to decide on the best registry. Can anyone suggest the pros/cons and the cost estimation required to create the below registries :

Private:

1. Azure Devops Artifacts
2. npm private registry
3. github registry

Public:

1. npm public registry
2. github public registry

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use Azure DevOps service, you can use [Azure DevOps Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/overview?view=azure-devops) by [creating feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/feeds?view=azure-devops) to store packages including the following package types:

- Maven
- npm
- NuGet
- Python
- Universal Packages.

In addition, Azure Artifacts offers a free-tier plan that includes 2 gigabytes (GiB) of free storage for different types of packages by reference to this doc: [Artifacts storage breakdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-storage?view=azure-devops).

You could review this doc: [Start using Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/start-using-azure-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to learn more about Azure Artifacts billing.

Comment: Thank you for yours response. I also wanted to know the pros and cons related to using the above mentioned registries

Comment: Sorry to this because I have only used Azure Artifacts and don't familiar the rest mentioned registries.